# How do I setup git on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, repository, installation

I am very new to the terminologies: git, repository and cloning.
I was able to search them all online and get pretty good grip on each (pretty simple stuff!).
But what I am trying to figure out now is how to "run" these instructions:

#### Clone repository for app:

```
git clone git://github.com/SampleLink.git
```

#### Update submodules:

```
git submodule update --init
```

I am running Windows7. I tried to run `init` through command prompt, but no luck.
Are these supposed to be run as individual commands or as one following the other in sequence automatically?
I am just not sure how to run these on my Windows machine and cannot seem to get any of it to work.

The submodule is a file within the initial repository.

I'm sorry if this is a lame question, but I have never needed to run this type of setup before.

Comment: What have you installed for using git on your machine? MSysGit (recommended)? TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [installing msysgit](http://help.github.com/win-git-installation/) in its ["Git for Windows" instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144082/different-between-msysgit-and-cygwin-git/3144417#3144417):
[Git-1.7.3.1-preview20101002.exe](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.7.3.1-preview20101002.exe&can=2&q=)

I like using [Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623518/msysgit-on-windows-what-should-i-be-aware-of-if-any), only adding the `git\bin` directory to the `PATH` environment variable, but without overriding some built-in windows tools.

From there, `git clone` [over http](https://github.com/blog/92-http-cloning) should work.

Comment: VonC, thanks for the detailed note on setup. I was able to get everything up and running and run git for the purposes above.