# Batch file to setup jdk from memory stick

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm doing a year in computer science at my university and it turns out there are very few computers that have the jdk installed on them. I can run eclipse portable from my memory stick, so compiling java should be possible.

What I was wanting was a batch file that set up the environment variables on the system so that I am able to run the portable version of the jdk from my memory stick. I don't appear to be able to alter the system variables but can change the user ones.

So far I have the below code as a batch file, though it still leaves me with a javac not recognize message when run. As a final note I should point out I don't have a great deal of experience with batch files.

```
echo %path% > stored_path.txt
setx PATH "%cd%PortableApps\CommonFiles\OpenJDK\bin;%PATH%"
setx JAVA_HOME "%cd%PortableApps\CommonFiles\OpenJDK"
setx CLASSPATH "%cd%PortableApps\CommonFiles\OpenJDK\bin;%CLASSPATH%"
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Update 04/10/13 - 16:54:

Just to clarify Eclipse itself works fine and is fully usable. However I have a jdk saved on the memory stick that works as if I call javac from a console that is open to that directory it works fine. What I want to know is if there is a way for windows to recognise this command from any directory on the system by just changing the user environment variables.

A thought that just occurred to me (I can't test it right now), is that would making a shortcut to the javac exe file in another folder work?

Comment: Try to run all the commands manually in a command line window. What does setx do?

Comment: Some more details about the OS of the computers you're trying to install the JDK on would be very helpful.

Comment: I had the same restrictions "back in the days", but I used the msysgit-shell from my USB-Stick. Here is a sample of how to set it up: https://gist.github.com/LukasKnuth/1992463

Comment: The university OS is windows 7 (the Computer Science building runs linux, but those have the JDK installed already). Lukas I'm afraid I have no idea what you're talking about with the msysgit-shell, it sounds like it may be some good if you could possibly explain that in some more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our school-computers didn't have git installed, so i put the portable version of [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/) on my USB-Stick. That gives you (aside from git) a portable [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS), which is a [bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) with most of the standard linux tools (like `ls` and `df`).

So, i used the shell, instead of the windows Command Line. Then, for the shell, I created a small bash-script to set up the environment-path's. From the gist:

> To make the script ("env_setup.sh") execute every time the git-shell
>   is started, you'll want to put the script into the "etc/"-directory in
>   your msysgit-folder.
>
> After that, you'll need to edit the "profile"-file, which is executed
>   by  the shell every time it's launched.
>
> Add the following line at
>   the end of the file:
>
> ```
> # Setup the environment-variables
> . /etc/env_setup.sh
> ```

This is the script, which sets up the environment variables:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Resources:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623518
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895
# http://markashleybell.com/articles/portable-git-windows-setting-home-environment-variable

# Get the directory this script is in:
DIR=$(cd $(dirname "$0"); pwd)
# Get only the Flash-Drive letter (e.g. "F")
FLASH=${DIR:1:1}
echo "We determined your USB-drive to be on $FLASH:\\"
# Set the home-path to the Flash-drive to get portable SSH-keys:
# --- You'll want to change this to your prefered Home-directory!
export HOME=/$FLASH/PortableApps/git/home/luke
echo "I set your Home-directory to '$HOME'";

### --- EXAMPLES ---

# Set the Java-Home variable to a JDK on USB-Stick:
export JAVA_HOME=/$FLASH/JDK1.6
# Add the Java-Tools to the JDK-folder:
export PATH=$PATH:/$FLASH/JDK1.6/bin

# Add a Maven from your USB-drive to the PATH:
export PATH=$PATH:/$FLASH/PortableApps/apache-maven/bin

# Add Node.js from the local pc to your PATH:
export PATH=$PATH:/c/Programms/nodejs
```

Here, you can see a few examples, including a JDK I had on the same USB-Stick. It is added to the `PATH`, so you can write `javac` everywhere you like and always use the JDK specified.

**Note** that this is only for one session and that it only works in the MSYS shell!

Answer (score 1):

**No need to actually set the environment variables permanently!**

Just set them for the current session of the program.  This is the batch script I made to launch my eclipse setup.

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd "%~dp0"
if not exist eclipse.exe exit /b 1
if not exist jdk1.6.0_45\ exit /b 2
if not exist apache-maven-2.2.1\ exit /b 3
set "JAVA_HOME=%~dp0\jdk1.6.0_45"
set "MAVEN=%~dp0\apache-maven-2.2.1"
set "M2_HOME=%MAVEN%"
set "MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
set "CLASSPATH=.;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\ext;%CLASSPATH%"
set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;%MAVEN%\bin;%PATH%"
rem M2_REPO
mklink /d jre "jdk1.6.0_45\jre"
start eclipse.exe -vm "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe" -data ".\workspace"
rem cmd /k
popd
endlocal
exit /b 0
```

This sets all that I need and starts eclipse with these settings without having to modify the variables.

My folder structure:

- eclipse\

  - jdk1.6.0_45\
  - apache-maven-2.2.1\
  - workspace\
  - eclipse.exe
  - all other eclipse folders and files.